# query criteria based on current day (sat/sun should return friday's value)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to figure out how to return daily results throughout the week while keeping Friday's results visible over the weekend. My current code isn't doing the trick - do I have to mess with arrays?

```
SELECT     ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 [Previous Day Sales]
FROM         PartsSales
WHERE     (MONTH(ClosedDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())) AND (YEAR(ClosedDate) =     YEAR(GETDATE())) AND (DAY(ClosedDate) = **case** DAY(GETDATE()) 
when 1 then 1 
when 2 then 2
when 3 then 3
when 4 then 4
when 5 then 5
when 6 then 5
when 7 then 5 end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `datepart` to find the current day of the week (1 = Sunday, 2 = Monday, etc), and then you can use `dateadd` to go back to Friday's date. If you convert `getdate()` to a date, then you'll always have the "midnight" at the begining of that day.

```
dateadd(
    day,
    case datepart(dw, getdate())
        when 1 then -- Sunday
            -2
        when 7 then -- Saturday
            -1
        else        -- Any other day
            0
    end,
    convert(date, getdate())
)
```

Is your ClosedDate a datetime datatype? You can make much better use of your indexes by checking for a date range, rather than pulling the dateparts out (using `year`/`month`/`day`). Below is an example with a lot of resused code in the `where` clause. Of course, if it is just a date datatype, you don't even need a range, since you are calculating the date.

Below is an example. It would be better if you used variables (if you're building this into a stored proc), or perhaps a derived/CTE table. I've kept things verbose for clarity.

```
SELECT     
    ROUND(COUNT(ClosedDate) / 10, 0) * 10 [Previous Day Sales]
FROM         
    PartsSales
WHERE
    ClosedDate between 
        -- Today/Friday's date:
        dateadd(
            day,
            case datepart(dw, getdate())
                when 1 then -- Sunday
                    -2
                when 7 then -- Saturday
                    -1
                else        -- Any other day
                    0
            end,
            convert(date, getdate())
        )
        and
        -- Add 1 day to the "Today/Friday" date. 
        -- This is the same logic as above, except wrapped in an extra dateadd to add 1 day to it.
        dateadd(
            day,
            1,
            dateadd(
                day,
                case datepart(dw, getdate())
                    when 1 then -- Sunday
                        -2
                    when 7 then -- Saturday
                        -1
                    else        -- Any other day
                        0
                end,
                convert(date, getdate())
            )
        )
```

Comment: Thanks SO much for your explanation. I'm newish to SQL and digest it slowly so I'm gonna go over your suggestions and will let you know if they work (for me). Thanks again!

Comment: @amart47 Good luck! SQL has some pretty abstract concepts to wrap your head around, and the best way to learn it is to keep getting your hands dirty.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that the code worked perfectly and served as a great lesson to me. I'm always surprised at how helpful strangers can be on here. Thank again

Comment: @amart47 I'm glad it worked for you. Hearing feedback that a solution worked is always good encouragement for strangers to want to keep helping people. :)

Comment: @amart47 Here's a little tidbit of information, since I see you're dividing count(*) by 10: in SQL, when you divide an integer by an integer (`count(*)` returns an int), it will return another integer, and not a float. This means that if you run `select 1 / 4`, you'll get a result of "0", because the decimal points get chopped off. So instead you have to convert one value to float. For example: `select 1 / convert(float, 4)` will return 0.25.